# Categorize register users in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to find a way to categorize my users when they are registering in the website, but I can't find any way. I also searched for some newsletter to have a category in it but I could not find anything useful.

I found this link:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-taxonomies/installation/ but i dont think

That's what I want. I want to categorize users and then use this categories in my newsletter.

Did anyone try to do the same thing, or does anyone have any tips?

Comment: You can add user meta fields for the registration process and then sort by that. Or you can use the newsletter software to have lists based on their choices when they fill out the form.

Comment: @Aibrean thank you for replaying. Do you know any specific newsletter plugin which capable to do this job?

Comment: I would use Gravity Forms paired with Mailchimp. I know Gravity Forms has the ability to register uses and also use mailchimp to connect responses to lists.